# how to print the mysql shell output table

Tags: python

in mysql shell print a table like this

[code][1]

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| PROXY              |
| bbs_bj             |
| bbs_bj_copy        |
| mysql              |
| octopus            |
| octopus_cp         |
| spider             |
+--------------------+
```

i want to print this table to the  printer keep right formate
is there any python package lib to hand this
or have some way to change the table to html and pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Just get the result of "show databases" query, and format the result what ever you want.To output as pdf, you may use some lib like pyPdf.